# set background color of all textboxes (input fields) to transparent

Tags: asp.net, css, textbox

I am upgrading part of a very old website. One of the pages that I own uses controls and dlls that I do not. There is one dll that puts a textbox (input field) on the page. This field is concepually a label but the person chose to use a textbox. Anyways, I can't change the dll.

Is there a way in my asp.net page that uses the dll to say all the textboxes on this page should have a transparent background?

This is the code I have access to. Any changes I make have to be made here.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="bodyContent" Runat="Server">
<style type="text/css">
.heading { color:#007DC3; font-weight:300; font-size:1.5em; line-height:1.22em; margin-bottom:22px; }
</style> 
    <cc1:wizard id="wizCtl" runat="server"></cc1:wizard>
</asp:Content>
```

Thanks!

like this?

```
<div style = "input[type='text']{ 
border: none; 
background-color: transparent; 
} 
">
    <cc1:wizard id="wizCtl" runat="server"></cc1:wizard>
</div>
```

It doesnt seem to work...

Tried this too:

```
<style input [type='text']{ border: none; background-color: transparent;} >

<cc1:wizard id="wizCtl" runat="server"></cc1:wizard>

</style>
```

Comment: Are you just wanting the textbox to look as though it isn't a textbox and only text?

Comment: well it does kinda look like it's text, but the background is white

Comment: OK... so why the down vote on the question? How is this a bad question...??? I was clear as to my situation and i've updated it as to the different things I have tried...???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see your problem.
Change your code to

```
<style type='text/css'>div.tbwrap input[type='text']{ border: none; background-color: transparent;}</style>
<div class='tbwrap'><cc1:wizard id="wizCtl" runat="server"></cc1:wizard></div>
```

Your style tag was a bit off and I do not thing the 'cc1:wizard' tag should have been within the style tag either.

Comment: HAHA. This worked!... But, It turned all of the textboxes, even the ones that are supposed to be textboxes, to background = transparent. Any chance I can say make all non-editable input fields have background = transparent?

Comment: It should only do it on text boxes that are wrapped in div.tbwrap though?

Comment: But that wizard generated all of the textboxes. Thats the whole thing, I don't have access to the code it generates, I can't tell it to apply div tags to certin textboxes. So because the wizard is in the div tags so are all of the textboxes...

Comment: Ah right I see now, sorry I am not familiar with ASP, im a PHP guy ^^ can I see the HTML code for all of the text boxes and what one you want to turn to a label, I need to see if any of them have any defining characteristics.

Comment: unfortunatly there arnt. Ive checked. Ther only think is the client IDs. I tried putting this in my css file: #ctl00$bodyContent$wizCtl$stepContent$AddressEdit1$txtFirstLabel {background-color:Transparent;} thats the client side id of the text box in question.

Comment: Could you append to your question the html of the text box you wish to apply this to, then I will be able to see what you mean easier and help you out more.

Comment: I think i'm just going to get the client ids of those textboxes and access them that way. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
input[type='text']{
border: none;
background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: I can't set their properties. They are in code that I can't change. Is there a way that I can say for all textboxes set background color to transparent?

Comment: If you stick that in your style tag it should do it.

Comment: If you still want the border then just take 'border: none;' out.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after:

```
<style>
  input {border:0;}
</style>
```

Comment: I don't want anythign to do with the border. I want to set the background to transparent.

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type='text']
{
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In the head part of the doc:

```
<style type="text/css">

   div#someDiv input[type='text']{ 
   background-color: transparent; 
   } 

</style>
```

Then wrap your textbox with div and give it an ID

```
<div id="someDiv">
    <cc1:wizard id="wizCtl" runat="server"></cc1:wizard> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="bodyContent" Runat="Server">
<style type="text/css">
.heading { color:#007DC3; font-weight:300; font-size:1.5em; line-height:1.22em; margin-bottom:22px; }
input[type='text']{
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}
</style> 
<cc1:wizard id="wizCtl" runat="server"></cc1:wizard> <!-- if this does transform into a text input, check the page source just to be certain -->
</asp:Content>
```